# Добавить элементы из списка в соответствующие ключи в словаре

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как добавлять элемент из списка под определенный ключ в словаре примерно выгладил так.

```
{'python':['python'], 'proj':['proj', 'proj']}
```

Но выводит так.

```
{'python': ['python', 'proj', 'proj'], 'proj': ['python', 'proj', 'proj']}
```

Вот код .

```
def func(*n):
    c=[]
    p={key:c for key in n}
    s=['python', 'proj', 'proj']
    for i in n:
        for h in s:
            if i in h:
                c.append(h)
                print('[+] yes', i,'-', h)
            else:
                print('[-] no', i,'-', h)
    print('-'*34)
    print(p)

func('python', 'proj')
```

Буду рад если предложите варианты.

Python 3.6

Comment: что у вас на входе? `('python', 'proj')` или `['python', 'proj', 'proj']` или и то и другое?

Comment: Да То и другое.  ('python', 'proj') добовляет ключ в словарь {'python':[], 'proj':[]}

Answer (score 1):

Имея ключи: `keys = ('python', 'proj')` и соответствующие значения `values = ['python', 'proj', 'proj']`, легко раскидать в словарь значения по ключям:

```
d = {k: [] for k in keys}
for v in values:
    d[v].append(v)
```

[Пример](https://ideone.com/W2Xa1I).

Знать `keys` не обязательно:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for v in values:
    d[v].append(v)
```

[Пример](https://ideone.com/8JUPgV).

Если задача, только те `values` добавить, которые в `keys` есть:

```
d = {k: [] for k in keys}
for v in values:
    if v in d:
        d[v].append(v)
```

[Пример](https://ideone.com/xrEUir).

Comment: БОЛЬШОЕ СПАСТБО.